# MFC Document View Getting Tabbing to work

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have created a MFC Document View app and added several classes which inherit from `CEdit` to the `CView`. I would like to get tabbing between each `CEdit` working. I have looked around and most solution involve Adding `IsDialogMessage()` to either the message loop or in `PreTranslateMessage`. I have tried this in the `PreTranslateMessage` method of the `CEdit` class like this:

```
BOOL WordControl::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if(IsDialogMessage(pMsg))
        return TRUE;
    else
        return __super::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

however, now the CEdit doesn't receive any keyboard messages and doesn't tab. I have created the `CEdit` like this:

```
Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | ES_CENTER , Rect, Parent, Index);
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The app uses the basic MFC single document
template. I am dynamically adding several objects which inherit from `CEdit` and several which inherit from `CStatic`. I have managed to create all the `CEdits` and `CStatics` but I would like to be able to tab from `CEdit` to `CEdit`.

A picture is worth a thousand words; here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to be able to type "hello" in the first `CEdit`, hit tab and for the next `CEdit` to have focus. Then I will type "world" and then hit tab and the next `CEdit` will have focus for me to type "this" etc.

**EDIT:**

New Window:

[image: New Window]

Comment: Any reason for not inheriting from CEditView? Can you show a mockup of the app to describe the issue a little more.

Comment: I am pretty new to using C++ and MFC so to tell you the truth I didn't know about CEditView. I am using the MFC single document template so I am just using what it gave me. Can I just change my view to inherit from `CEditView` instead?

Comment: Sure. Is it tabbing between the views you're trying to get working?

Comment: I tried changing the view to inherit from `CEditView` as per your suggestion but the app gave a Debug Exception failure on startup.

Comment: For something like this you'd normally create a view based on CFormView. Then you'll have a dialog resource that you can add edits to, specify tab order etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: The only other consideration is that I am creating the `CStatic` and `CEdits` dynamically so I won't be using the dialog resource. Is using a `CFormView` still going to be my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CFormView as your base. You can add controls dynamically and the form will manage the tabbing for you. If you only have a small number of maximum edit controls you could also just create them on the form and then show/hide them as necessary.

Comment: Your suggestion works! As you will see on my edit a new dialog pops up asking for me to select an option and click OK. After I make a selection the main app loads and the tabbing works, thank you. But I want the app to just load as it did before without the new window. Can you suggest how to get the app to load as it did before?

Comment: You'll need to edit the InitInstance in your CWinApp class. If you just get rid of the DocTemplate creation for the previous CView it should sort it out.

Comment: That sorted it out thanks. I wish I could give you more than 1 up vote, thanks so much for your help.